# Clojure: how can I bind a form to the global javascript namespace?

Tags: javascript, clojure, closures, clojurescript

I've got a clojure project in which I am generating some JavaScript.  Note that this is a *clojure* project, not a clojurescript project.

Right now my project.clj has (among other things):

```
:dependencies [[org/clojurescript "0.0-1806"]]
```

In my clojure, I'm using:

```
(ns blah
  (:require [cljs.closure :as cljs])

(defn trivial-example []
  (cljs/build '(defn foo [] "bar")
              {:optimizations :advanced :pretty-print true}))
```

This works well enough.  When I call (blah/trivial-example) I get a nice javascript output:

```
"cljs.b.a = function() {\n  return\"bar\"\n};\n"
```

**Question:**  How can I bind the function `foo` as a global variable (as window.foo or whatever)?  I don't want it to be `cljs.b.a`, I want it to be accessible via JavaScript as `foo()` (or any other name I select via code).

**Note:** I tried this as recommended elsewhere:

```
(aset js/window "foo" foo)
```

But I got an error that said:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such namespace: js, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)
```

From which I take it I need to get access some sort of js namespace that cljs.closure understands as the JavaScript namespace...

Help? =)

Comment: I think that you need externs file, read http://lukevanderhart.com/2011/09/30/using-javascript-and-clojurescript.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ^:export, for more info http://lukevanderhart.com/2011/09/30/using-javascript-and-clojurescript.html

```
(ns cmpl.core
  (:require [cljs.closure :as cljs]))

(defn trivial-example []
  (cljs/build '[(ns cmpl.core)
                (defn ^{:export foo} foo [] "bar")]
              {:optimizations :advanced
               :pretty-print true}))
```

Output:

```
"undefined" !== typeof Math.imul && (Math.imul.a ? Math.imul.a(4294967295, 5) : Math.imul.call(null, 4294967295, 5));
function a() {
  return "bar";
}
var b = ["foo"], c = this;
b[0] in c || !c.execScript || c.execScript("var " + b[0]);
for (var d;b.length && (d = b.shift());) {
  b.length || void 0 === a ? c = c[d] ? c[d] : c[d] = {} : c[d] = a;
}
;
```

test in node.js (copy&paste code and call foo):

```
→  node
> "undefined" !== typeof Math.imul && (Math.imul.a ? Math.imul.a(4294967295, 5) : Math.imul.call(null, 4294967295, 5));
false
> function a() {
...   return "bar";
... }
undefined
> var b = ["foo"], c = this;
undefined
> b[0] in c || !c.execScript || c.execScript("var " + b[0]);
true
> for (var d;b.length && (d = b.shift());) {
...   b.length || void 0 === a ? c = c[d] ? c[d] : c[d] = {} : c[d] = a;
... }
[Function: a]
> ;
undefined
> foo
[Function: a]
> foo()
'bar'
```